# Split a zip-file into chunks with Python

Tags: python, zip, filesplitting

I have a piece of a code which creates a zip file successfully, but I need to split this file if the size of it is more that 1MB.

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
    from split_file_reader.split_file_writer import SplitFileWriter
    import zipfile

    # make element tree
    tree = etree.ElementTree(batch_element)

    # make xml file and write it in stream
    xml_object = BytesIO()
    tree.write(xml_object, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=False, encoding="utf-8")
    xml_file = xml_object.getvalue()

    final = BytesIO()

    with SplitFileWriter(final, 1_000_000) as sfw:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(sfw, "a") as zip_file:
            zip_file.writestr('Batch.xml', xml_file)
```

I want to retrieve the split file as bytes. The zipping part is working, but the splitting doesn't.

Comment: You seem to be using https://pypi.org/project/split-file-reader/; probably [edit] to include this information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [split_file_reader docs](https://gitlab.com/Reivax/split_file_reader/-/tree/master/src/split_file_writer#arguments), the first argument of `SplitFileWriter` can be a generator that produces file-like objects. That will allow you to split the zip-file into a list of `BytesIO` chunks.

Here is a working example script:

```
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO
from lxml import etree
from split_file_reader.split_file_writer import SplitFileWriter

# make element tree
# tree = etree.ElementTree(batch_element)
tree = etree.parse('/tmp/test.xml')

# make xml file and write it in stream
xml_object = BytesIO()
tree.write(xml_object, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=False, encoding="utf-8")
xml_file = xml_object.getvalue()

chunks = []

def gen(lst):
    while True:
        lst.append(BytesIO())
        yield lst[-1]

with SplitFileWriter(gen(chunks), 1_000_000) as sfw:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(sfw, "w") as zip_file:
        zip_file.writestr('Batch.xml', xml_file)

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    print(f'chunk {i}: {len(chunk.getvalue())}')
```

Output:

```
chunk 0: 1000000
chunk 1: 1000000
chunk 2: 1000000
chunk 3: 1000000
chunk 4: 1000000
chunk 5: 887260
```

Comment: [Here is a corrected link to the docs](https://gitlab.com/Reivax/split_file_reader/-/tree/master/src/split_file_writer#arguments)  The package structure has changed.  I am the author of this project, and this is an acceptable answer.  You may also yield the same BytesIO object forever, and simply truncate it each time, doing your post-processing in the generator immediately as the BytesIO fills, instead of after the full file is written, thus saving memory.

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs for the module which you are using, which is [https://pypi.org/project/split-file-reader](https://pypi.org/project/split-file-reader/)

It should have the usage instructions in there.

EDIT: This is an example:

```py
with SplitFileWriter("split.zip.", 500_000) as sfw:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file=sfw, mode='w') as zipf:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./"):
            for file in files:
                if file.startswith("random_payload"):
                    zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: i have seen the docs but there isn't much. since it new library. in the example here is simple version where it saves the files in some location, but i want to retrieve it as byte variable